# Why is xcb_key_symbols_alloc returning NULL on big screens?

Tags: linux, x11, xcb

I am calling `xcb_key_symbols_alloc` in my code (which i am testing in Xephyr). If the screen is smaller (e.g. 960x540), everything works fine, but when i try it on a bigger screen (e.g. 1280x720), it suddenly starts returning NULL. It also works if i put it on my main display (where gnome is running), it suddenly starts working again.

Why is this happening and how would go about i fix it?

Comment: There is no no magic in `xcb_key_symbols_alloc` [see](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxcb-keysyms/-/blob/691515491a4a3c119adc6c769c29de264b3f3806/keysyms/keysyms.c). There are *very* few reasons why it can return NULL.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Ah, ok, thank you so much! I will go figure out what it is that is causing my issue then. :)

Comment: I changing the size makes it happen I'll bet for the `malloc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening and how would go about i fix it?

Let's look at the source code! Debian Codesearch found https://sources.debian.org/src/xcb-util-keysyms/0.4.0-1/keysyms/keysyms.c/?hl=74#L74

There are three cases for this function to return `NULL`.

```c
  if (!c || xcb_connection_has_error(c))
    return NULL;
```

You are passing in a `NULL` pointer or a XCB connection that is already broken.

```c
  syms = malloc (sizeof (xcb_key_symbols_t));
  if (!syms)
    return NULL;
```

A memory allocation failure.

If I had to guess, I would say that your XCB connection is broken / is in an error state. Since you say this is about the size of the root window, you are perhaps doing a too large `PutImage` request earlier?

A random `printf`-debugging idea would be to put `printf("I am here and state is %d\n", xcb_connection_has_error(c))` in some random places and use that to figure out where exactly the connection breaks / goes into an error state.

Comment: Yep, that was the exact issue hah! Thanks! :)